# Call method after hiding keyboard iOS

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have textview on iPad. I have handled events on done click of textview. But however iPad lower right hide keyboard button behaves differently on click. It should call the same methods which are called in done click. However it doesn't happen. Is there any any other method which is called?

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the "hide" button on the keyboard doesn't call the method you've set up to be called with the "Done" or "Return" key. Pressing the hide button calls `resignFirstResponder` on the keyboard, and hides it.

If you want your method to be called every time the keyboard is dismissed:

First be aware for keyboard notifications

Objective-C:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(onKeyboardHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Swift:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
```

then use

Objective-C:

```
- (void)keyboardDidHide: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    // Do something here
}
```

Swift:

```
func keyboardDidHide(sender: NSNotification) 
{
    //Do something here
}
```

Check out the docs for [using the keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html), and [UIResponder](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/resignFirstResponder).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
if ([text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    //done button pressed
}
return YES;
}
```